# Scss : Selector Inheritance : removing one declaration

Tags: inheritance, sass

Is there a way to remove the declaration from the extended selector in scss?

Example would be:

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 28px;
  background: url("/images/logo.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  a {
    @extend #logo;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -999999em;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Rather than using

> background: none;

Comment: What is wrong with the compiled CSS exactly?

Comment: Nothing massively wrong, but I wonder if there is a way of accomplishing it without the compiled file displaying 'background: none;' for #logo a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "undo". you'll have to create a separate selector that both selectors extend from:

```
%logo-common {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 28px;
}

#logo {
  @extend %logo-common;
  background: url("/images/logo.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  a {
    @extend %logo-common;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -999999em;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
#logo, #logo a {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 28px;
}

#logo {
  background: url("/images/logo.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
#logo a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -999999em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The percentage symbol does seem to cause problem?

Comment: See [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders)